# Getting error -1426 when trying to transfer files from iPhone via iTunes File Sharing

Tags: macos, iphone, itunes, file-sharing

I'm getting error -1426 when trying to transfer files from iPhone via iTunes File Sharing. I'm on iOS 12.4 and macOS 10.14.6. iPhone is XS Max 256GB and Mac is MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015) 16GB RAM, 256GB SSD (APFS Encrypted).

It's a 1.8GB audio file. I have 22GB free space on the Mac.

Console shows this error when it happens:

```
error   17:38:08.029393 -0700   iTunes  AFC OpenFile failed (0xE8004001) for "<private>" for mode 1 with connection 0x7ff3b4156e00
```

Disk utility gives no errors on the main volume.

Answer (score 2):

I don't recall ever seeing that specific error code with iTunes before.

However, when it comes to the other 14xx<sup>*</sup> error codes I've seen, the fix is usually doing one of the following:

- Restart your Mac (or PC) and change the USB port you're using
- Restart your Mac (or PC) and change the USB cable you're using

If neither of these works, reinstalling iTunes may resolve the issue.

Another option worth trying is to download and install iTunes 12.6.3 (this can be installed alongside newer versions of iTunes).

Refer to [Deploy apps in a business environment with iTunes](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT208079) on Apple's website for further information and download links.

Let me know if none of the above works.

<sup>*</sup> More specifically, error codes 1413, 1415, 1417, 1418 and 1428.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure about the AFC (.afc) format file? I have had a similar trouble a few month ago, and my MacBook Pro looks a lot like yours (mid 2015, 16GB, etc), but my audio file was a ’.aac’, as far as I remember (a concert of Angelo Branduardi, from a backup of iTunes files from Windows), and the issue was due to iTunes itself, in my opinion —— perhaps due to version of my AAC file (no more maintained?).

I have lost my file, by the way, and finally fired all my .aac files, as most of them crashed my Mac. (I have just verified, I only have .m4a & .mp3 now).

If not too late, could you try this:

1. Import the file on your Mac with any utility (not iTunes itself), then
2. Try to import the file into iTunes (or to open it with iTunes),
   to see if you still have the trouble (so iTunes is guilty) or not?

Whatever the wrongdoer, could you look which audio types your iTunes library hosts, as follows:

1. Open Terminal (it's in the Applications > Utilities folder)
2. Go to the root of your iTunes music files by entering one of the following commands in Terminal:

   `cd "Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music"`

   `cd ~/"Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Music"`

(Note: due to the space in ‘iTunes Media’ folder name, the quotes are mandatory.)

3. ask the system for your audio files with this command:

   `find . -type f -print | awk -F'.' '{printf("%s\n",$NF);}' | sort | uniq`

or use

`/usr/bin/find . -type f -print | /usr/bin/awk -F'.' '{printf("%s\n",$NF);}' | /usr/bin/sort | /usr/bin/uniq`

If you get message(s) about something "not found" (all the commands must be typed on a single line, but cut & paste are allowed).